# Delete method not working in Newman ( Postman tool for command line)

Tags: postman

I am using newman tool to run my postman tests on command line. Get and Post method seems to be working fine but Delete method is not deleting the resource but give status 200 OK. Please see the screen shot. On Postman gui tool it works fine.

[image: 200 OK status code returned through command line but the it does not delete the resource actually]

Comment: Please mask the server/host name details.

Comment: @notionquest  - masked it! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the curl from chrome network tool while performing DELETE using POSTMAN Chrome client and saw that it does use postman token in the request header. Added Postman Token to header for Delete operation in newman and it works fine.